# SQL Union 2 table with union with one table having column as null

Tags: sql

For given example , i am planing to do a union of 2 tables

```
table A
country_code  | arrg_id  | arrg_desc
sg              test1       est_desc
..               ..          ..

table B
country_code  | arrg_desc 
sg              test_2
```

given an example above, i would like to union both of this 2 table.

i have came out with query

```
select Business as 'Retail' , country_code as country , arrg_id as arrg_id from table_A
union
select Business as 'Retail' , country_code as, 'NA' as arrg_id from table_b
```

as i run the query specified, i was receiving error on : error: (HY000, None) AnalysisException: Incompatible return types 'DOUBLE' and 'STRING'

However if i cast as string, this would work

```
select Business as 'Retail' , country_code as country , cast(arrg_id as String) as arrg_id from table_A
union
select Business as 'Retail' , country_code as, 'NA' as arrg_id from table_b
```

i was wondering if this would be the best approach or it will disturb the integrity of the data , would need some advices on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule of thumb for taking a union between two (or more) tables is that the types of columns in both halves of the union should always be the same.  Presumably here, the `arrg_id` in the A table is numeric.  This means that if you want to union this value with the string literal `'NA'`, then you would either need the cast in your example above, or, you would need to union `arrg_id` with another numeric value (e.g. perhaps -1).  So, the query you suggested with the cast to string is correct.

Comment: Great, this gave some in depth on how i can handle the data integrity , i feel putting it as -1 would be a better approach to not disturb integrity of the data . Thanks !!!

Comment: Or use `NULL`!  Which would be the "standard" in such cases.